# A normal discord bot hosted on replit running live for more than a month

Tags: express, discord, discord.js, replit

I don't know what happened. A live bot on repl.it had been running for more than a month goes offline suddenly.

```
        console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    })
```

This part doesn't happen to work. I tried changing the login id as well and updated it. The server on which it is hosted works the bot doesn't goes live somehow :(

Comment: I'd bet the bot's access token expired.

Comment: I reset the token and updated it as well but doesn't work as well totally confused :(

Comment: This happened to me yesterday with a bot I've been hosting. Kind of weird. I guess it's a repl.it bug.

Comment: @bread_2 this is kinda sad :(

Comment: So repl.it is a shared hosting service, if there are anybots on your shared server that have been banned by Discord (IP ban) it blocks all bots from that server from connecting. Try downloading your bot to your local pc and running it locally to see if it connects. If it does, then that is your issue.

Comment: Agree with @Gh0st, it's called a rate limit. There's a Replit trick that if you run `kill 1` in the shell it switches your IP and the bot works again, but only for a short amount of time.